# Manifolds, where its enough to have one chart for integration

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Question from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605589/manifolds-where-its-enough-to-have-one-chart-for-integration , after getting no answer. (comments there indicate that all manifolds should have property **, is there a simple proof avoiding things like results from riemannian geometry?)

Assume a compact connected manifold $M$ is given as a subset of some $\mathbb{R}^m$. Assume we have a chart $\gamma:U \rightarrow M$ such that $M-f(U)$ (the set $M$ without $f(U)$) has zero measure in $M$ and call this property **. Then its enough to have this one chart to calculate the volume of $M$ (example: remove a point from a sphere). While there is the construction of a partition of one to calculate the volume in case one needs more charts, I think I never saw an example of a calculation where $M$ did not have the property ** and one really had to construct a partition of unity.(Simple textbook examples like, spheres, torus etc all seem to have property **)
So can one classify all such manifolds having property **?

Comment: It follows from Morse theory that any smooth manifold is homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex with only one top-dimensional cell. For such a CW-complex your property (**) holds because the cells of positive codimension have measure 0. The problem is of course that Morse theory provides only a homotopy equivalence and not necessarily a diffeomorphism, so we do not know whether the conclusion holds for the manifold itself.

Comment: @ThiKu - it holds, Take Morse function $f$ with one minimum and cut its critical points with half of incoming stable manifolds of the gradient flow of $f$. The rest is an open ball.

Comment: Pick a triangulation of your manifold and let $U'$ be the union of the interiors of the $n$-simplices.  Thus $U'$ is the disjoint union of at most countably many open balls.  You can take $U'$ to be your chart.  If you want you chart to be connected, then let $G$ be the graph whose vertices are the $n$-simplices and where two vertices are joined by an edge if the associated simplices share a codimension 1 face.  Pick a maximal tree $T$ in $G$, and define $U$ to be the result of taking $U'$ and drilling a small hole between any two simplices joined in $T$.  Then $U$ is diffeomorphic to a ball.